# How can I pass values from a file to parameters in a shell command?

Tags: shell

I am learning how to create scripts in the unix shell. I have a list of genome coordinates that I would like to pass as values to the command line. For example, I have the file `Chr1.txt`:

```
Chr1   10    450
Chr1   456   890
...
```

The shell command is:

```
maf_parse  --start *value1*   --end *value2*
```

I would like to iteratively run the shell command with the start (`$2`) and end (`$3`) coordinates from `Chr1.txt`. I have ~1000 entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read chr1 start end
do
    maf_parse --start "$start" --end "$end"
done < Chr1.txt
```

Read each line into three variables; run the command.  You could use `read -r` if you wanted to, but it is not necessary with the data you show.

> I don't understand the `< Chr1.txt` at the end. Does it mean "read from"?

It's input redirection, just the same as anywhere else, except it redirects input to the whole `while read ...; do ...; done` loop.  If the program `maf_parse` might read from standard input, you need to use a different redirection — see the example below.

> Moreover, let's say that I have a fourth field ($4) with a name and would like to save each iteration's result in a file with the name; how could I modify your script?

Assuming you have Bash, you can do the read redirection as shown ([`read -u 3`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read) and `3< Chr1.txt`).  The rest is neutral between Bourne-like shells.

```
while read -u 3 chr1 start end file junk
do
    maf_parse --start "$start" --end "$end" > "$file"
done 3< Chr1.txt
```

The `3`'s mean use file descriptor 3 instead of 0 (standard input) as the input file descriptor.  This leaves the program able to read standard input if it wants to.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't understand the < Chr1.txt at the end. Does it mean "read from"? Moreover, let's say that I have a fourth field ($4) with a name and would like to save each iteration's result in a file with the name, how could I modify your script ?